# Find strings enclosed within different types of double quotes

Tags: c#, .net, regex, .net-core

I am writing a Regex to extract string enclosed within different type of double quotes (`"`, `“`, `”`).

So far I have written below code, it works as expected but the regex is quite big and I think it can be improved.

```
//mergeField = {{field(“dd/MMM/yyyy")}}
var startIndex = mergeField.IndexOf('(');
var endIndex = mergeField.IndexOf(')');
string format = mergeField.Substring(startIndex: startIndex + 1, length: endIndex - startIndex - 1);

string formatSpecifierPattern = string.Format(@"{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}|{4}|{5}", @"(\“.*?\”)|(\”.*?\”)", "\\\"(.*?)\\\"", "“(.*?)\\\"", "\\\"(.*?)“", "”(.*?)\\\"", "\\\"(.*?)”");
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(format, formatSpecifierPattern);
```

In above code, mergeField is passed as a parameter and it can have a different combination of quotes. Is there any way I can simplify my Regex and handle all combinations (`"`, `“`, `”`)

Input - Expected Output

```
{{field(“dd/MMM/yyyy")}} -> “dd/MMM/yyyy"
{{field("dd/MMM/yyyy“)}} -> "dd/MMM/yyyy“
{{field("dd/MMM/yyyy")}} -> "dd/MMM/yyyy"
{{field(“dd/MMM/yyyy“)}} -> “dd/MMM/yyyy“
{{field(“dd/MMM/yyyy“)}} -> “dd/MMM/yyyy“
{{field(”dd/MMM/yyyy")}} -> ”dd/MMM/yyyy"
{{field("dd/MMM/yyyy”)}} -> "dd/MMM/yyyy”
{{field(”dd/MMM/yyyy”)}} -> ”dd/MMM/yyyy”
```

Comment: Do you have a specific input? Can you tell us a bit more about the why ? If you are trying to harmonize you can perhaps simply simply split on those chars? Or replace them?

Comment: Maybe `(["“”].*?["“”])` will be sufficient?

Comment: You are perhaps looking for a simple `([“"”].+?[“"”])` like https://regex101.com/r/G8EU1s/1/, in C# it will be `string pattern = @"([“""”].+?[“""”])";`

Comment: Btw., in a verbatim string (`@"..."`) double quotes are escaped by doubling them. I.e., `"` becomes `""`, not by using a backslash in C#. And you don't need to escape these different types of quotes in regex either.

Comment: @Drag and Drop, this is a business requirement and the end output of the `{{field(“dd/MMM/yyyy")}}` will be `08/Feb/2021` (Or whatever data comes from DB). And what do you mean by split chars / replace? Could you please explain?

Comment: My question were about the next step. Because it look like X/Y problem, where you try to find something. Write complicate regex and down the line you change every "_bad_" into valid quote. Because the whole exercise make me think of a recent occurence of one trying to fix Html stample that had been vandalized by Outlook using regex.

Comment: @Drag and Drop, the solution which you have given in comment works as expected, could you please put it as answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you care about is `<one kind of quote> <some text> <one kind of quote>` and the kind of quote doesn't matter, then all you need to do is:

`["“”](.*?)["“”]`

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/8IGPuG/1)

Explanation:

- `["“”]`: One of these characters
- `(.*?)`: As many of any character as possible, but [lazy match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)
- `["“”]`: One of these characters

If the `<some text>` has a format you know, you could also specify that to prevent capturing some other text enclosed in quotes (if that is a possibility)

For example:
`["“”]\d{1,2}/\w{3}/\d{4}["“”]` will match `"08/Feb/2021"`, but not `"dd/MMM/yyyy"` or `"abcdefgh"`
[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/asDRwJ/1/)